# React Customize Google calendar's tooltip does't appear

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api

I am using this api to create customize google calendar.
https://github.com/ericz1803/react-google-calendar

Here are the codeSandbox for demo, the tooltip is perfectly working.
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-rgb-2y3t7?file=/src/App.js

Then, I copied the same code into mine project with all path, API ... changed.
Every things works well, but the tooltip doesn't appear any more.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Calendar from "@ericz1803/react-google-calendar";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

const API_KEY = "AIzaSyAKzScoADeBmp6qUsEzrwZhLqb6WARNFOo";

//replace calendar id with one you want to test

let calendars = [
  { calendarId: "c_7q0ai3mn1p9b880f7llhbnv364@group.calendar.google.com" }
];

let styles = {
  //you can use object styles
  calendar: {
    borderWidth: "3px" //make outer edge of calendar thicker
  },

  today: css`
    /* highlight today by making the text red and giving it a red border */
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
  `
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body>
        <div
          style={{
            width: "90%",
            paddingTop: "50px",
            paddingBottom: "50px",
            margin: "auto",
            maxWidth: "1200px"
          }}
        >
          <Calendar apiKey={API_KEY} calendars={calendars} styles={styles} />
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by tooltip? The popup that show event details when user clicks on event name?

Comment: @GauravVichare yes, the pop up

Comment: is package @emotion/react installed?

Comment: @GauravVichare both `npm install --save react react-dom @emotion/react`  and  
 `npm install --save @ericz1803/react-google-calendar` are installed

Answer (score 0):

There is open issue for same on [github](https://github.com/ericz1803/react-google-calendar/issues/25).

Till it gets fixed, use the same version of the package which is used in the sandbox demo, it doesn't have that bug.

```
"@ericz1803/react-google-calendar": "4.0.1"
```

Comment: I have tried use same package version as mine in CodeSandbox. It still work perfectly in the demo project.